# Polynomial Java Array add subtract

Tags: java, arrays, polynomials

I have the below code, all seems to work fine, except for the `sub()` function when attempting to subtract one polynomial from another

```
p4 = p1.sub(p2);
```

I see the output: `x+3x^5-5x^8`, when I expect to see: `x-2x^3+7x^5-2x^7-5x^8`. I cannot figure out what is wrong with my code, any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
public class Polynomial {

public static final int MAX_NUMBER_OF_COEFFICIENTS = 30;
private int[] coefficients = new int[MAX_NUMBER_OF_COEFFICIENTS];

public Polynomial() {
}

public Polynomial(int coefficient, int exponent) {
    coefficients[exponent] += coefficient;
}

public Polynomial(int[] newcoefficients) {
    for (int i = 0 ; i < MAX_NUMBER_OF_COEFFICIENTS; i++) {
        coefficients[i] += newcoefficients[i];
    }
}

public void insert(int coefficient, int exponent) {
    coefficients[exponent] += coefficient;
}

public Polynomial add(Polynomial otherPolynomial) {
    for (int i = 0 ; i < MAX_NUMBER_OF_COEFFICIENTS; i++) {
        if (otherPolynomial.coefficients[i] != 0)
            this.coefficients[i] += otherPolynomial.coefficients[i];
    }
    return new Polynomial(this.coefficients);
}

public Polynomial sub(Polynomial otherPolynomial) {
    for (int i = 0 ; i < MAX_NUMBER_OF_COEFFICIENTS; i++) {
        if (otherPolynomial.coefficients[i] != 0)
            this.coefficients[i] -= otherPolynomial.coefficients[i];
    }
    return new Polynomial(this.coefficients);
}

public void sub(int coefficient, int exponent) {
    this.coefficients[exponent] -= coefficient;
}

public void remove(int exponent) {
    coefficients[exponent] = 0;
}

public void printout() {
    boolean firstPrint = false;
    if (coefficients[0] != 0) {
        System.out.print(coefficients[0]);
        firstPrint = true;
    }
    for (int i = 1 ; i < MAX_NUMBER_OF_COEFFICIENTS; i ++) {
        if (coefficients[i] != 0) {
            if (firstPrint == false) {
                System.out.print(coefficients[i] + "x^" + i);
                firstPrint = true;
            }
            else {
                System.out.print(" + " + coefficients[i] + "x^" + i);
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Polynomial p1 = new Polynomial(1,1);
    Polynomial p2 = new Polynomial(2,3);
    Polynomial p3 = new Polynomial();
    Polynomial p4 = new Polynomial();
    Polynomial p5 = new Polynomial(6,3);

    try {
        p1.insert(3,5);
        p1.sub(5,8);
        p1.printout();
        p2.sub(4,5);
        p2.add(new Polynomial(2,7));
        p2.printout();
        p3 = p1.add(p2);
        p3.printout();
        p4 = p1.sub(p2);
        p4.printout();
        p5.insert(2,5);
        p5.remove(3);
        p5.printout();
        //p1.add(new Polynomial(2,-1));
    }
    catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
            System.out.println("Exponent cannot be negative. " + e);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I suggest you learn how to use a debugger.

Comment: Thanks, but I am using a debugger, I just can't seem to understand, why I'm receiving the output x+3x^5-5x^8 from p1.sub(p2), when I expect to see x-2x^3+7x^5-2x^7-5x^8.

Comment: Why do you expect that output?

Comment: If you work this subtraction of polynomials (in this instance P1-P2) out on paper, (x + 3x^5- 5x^8)-(2x^3- 4x^5+ 2x^7), you should get: x - 2x^3+7x^5- 2x^7- 5x^8. Basically, the p1.sub(p2), is literally just outputting the same printout() of P1, not sure why this is occurring.

Comment: You are not following what is happening to `coefficients` in both `add` and `sub`. See my answer for more detail, and give special focus for the edit

Answer (score 2):

The function is working as expected. What you are not aware of (maybe you are) is that when you call `p3 = p1.add(p2);` you will change `p1` and then return a new polynomial with `p1`'s coefficients. So when you call `p4 = p1.sub(p2)` you will have the same `p1` that was before the `p3 = p1.add(p2)`.
So what you were having was more like this:

`p3 = p1* = p1 + p2`

`p4 = p1** = p1* - p2`

Where `p1*` is the result of `p1 + p2`. So what you have now was:

`p4 = p1* - p2 = (p1 + p2) - p2 = p1`

Again, if you want to return new polynomial, DONT CHANGE THE EXISTING ONE.

Change both functions `add(Polynomial ..)` and `sub(Polynomial ..)`:

```
public Polynomial add(Polynomial otherPolynomial) {
    int coeff[] = new int[MAX_NUMBER_OF_COEFFICIENTS];
    System.arraycopy(this.coefficients, 0, coeff, 0, MAX_NUMBER_OF_COEFFICIENTS);
    for (int i = 0 ; i < MAX_NUMBER_OF_COEFFICIENTS; i++) {
        // why is this anyway?
        //if (otherPolynomial.coefficients[i] != 0)
        coeff[i] += otherPolynomial.coefficients[i];
    }
    return new Polynomial(coeff);
}

public Polynomial sub(Polynomial otherPolynomial) {
    int coeff[] = new int[MAX_NUMBER_OF_COEFFICIENTS];
    System.arraycopy(this.coefficients, 0, coeff, 0, MAX_NUMBER_OF_COEFFICIENTS);
    for (int i = 0 ; i < MAX_NUMBER_OF_COEFFICIENTS; i++) {
        // why is this anyway?
        //if (otherPolynomial.coefficients[i] != 0)
        coeff[i] -= otherPolynomial.coefficients[i];
    }
    return new Polynomial(coeff);
}
```

This way, you wont change `p1` when you are assigning (or calling copy constructor on) `p3` and `p4`.

---

EDIT:
Based on your code, it is IMPOSSIBLE to have one function that once adds to the original caller and once doesn't change it, which is what your program wants. When you call `p2.add(new Polynomial(2,7));` you want to change `p2` and in the same time you want `p1.add(p2)` not to change `p1` which is impossible to achieve in one function.

If you want to have the output you suggested in your question, change

`p2.add(new Polynomial(2,7));`

to

`p2 = p2.add(new Polynomial(2,7));`

---

EDIT2: If I wanted to do it, I would really do it a whole different way. I would have all `add/sub` functions with `void` return types, and have two static `add/sub` functions that return new `Polynomial` and accept `two Polynomials`. These `static` methods cannot be called on an instance (like `p1`) but can only be called on the class.

Therefore, this would be my code if I was designing it:

```
public static Polynomial add(Polynomial p1, Polynomial p2){
    Polynomial newPolynomial = new Polynomial();
    for(int i=0;i< MAX_NUMBER_OF_COEFFICIENTS;i++)
    newPolynomial.coefficients[i] = p1.coefficients[i]+p2.coefficients[i];
    return newPolynomial;
}

public static Polynomial sub(Polynomial p1, Polynomial p2){
    Polynomial newPolynomial = new Polynomial();
    for(int i=0;i< MAX_NUMBER_OF_COEFFICIENTS;i++)
        newPolynomial.coefficients[i] = p1.coefficients[i]-p2.coefficients[i];
    return newPolynomial;
}

public void add(Polynomial otherPolynomial) {
    for (int i = 0 ; i < MAX_NUMBER_OF_COEFFICIENTS; i++) {
        coefficients[i] += otherPolynomial.coefficients[i];
    }
}

public void sub(Polynomial otherPolynomial) {
    for (int i = 0 ; i < MAX_NUMBER_OF_COEFFICIENTS; i++) {
        coefficients[i] -= otherPolynomial.coefficients[i];
    }
}
```

When you have it this way, you CANNOT say `p3.add(p1, p2)`. This will change your main code to:

```
    p1.insert(3,5);
    p1.sub(5,8);
    p1.printout();
    p2.sub(4,5);
    p2.add(new Polynomial(2,7));
    p2.printout();
    p3 = Polynomial.add(p1, p2);
    p3.printout();
    p4 = Polynomial.sub(p1, p2);
    p4.printout();
    p5.insert(2,5);
    p5.remove(3);
    p5.printout();
```

As you can see for `p3` and `p4` you will be calling `Polynomial.add` and `Polynomial.sub`. You can best understand this by understanding `Math.*` methods. All `Math` library is `static` so you cannot create an instance of it, but you can say `Math.abs`... Here it is the same concept, you can call `Polynomial.add` and so on

Answer (score 1):

In your code you are mixing two concepts.

1) (**Immutable Ojects**) Either you should code your Polynomial as immutable,  that is add and sub do not alter the member field but create a new array and return a new object - in this case you have to write

```
Polynomial p3 = p1.add(p2)
```

and p1 remains unchanged -, or

2) (**Mutable Objects**) you should code your Polynomial as mutable and return just this (and NOT create an return a new object) - in this case you can write

```
p1.add(p2)
```

which similar to p1 = p1.add(p2) in the case 1.

In case 2) you can do

```
  p1.add(p2).sub(p3)
```

which is similar to
p1 = p1.add(p2).sub(p3) in case 1).

What you are observing is called a ***side effect***, since your operation is modifying the object. Avoiding side effects is maybe one of the main motivation of writing code that leaves object immutable.

Try

```
public Polynomial add(Polynomial otherPolynomial) {
    Polynomial result = new Polynomial();
    for (int i = 0 ; i < MAX_NUMBER_OF_COEFFICIENTS; i++) {
        if (otherPolynomial.coefficients[i] != 0)
            result.coefficients[i] = this.coefficients[i] + otherPolynomial.coefficients[i];
    }
    return result;
}
```

and similar for sub.

Search the keywords immutable, mutable and side effect for more details.

Comment: isn't it more of immutable method than an immutable object? p1 does change in other methods without the need to create new polynomial and assign it to p1. This isn't like `string` where the library creates a new string when you change its content.

Answer (score 0):

Looks fine to me you start with line

```
Polynomial p1 = new Polynomial(1,1);
```

Which is basically 1*x then you call the following line

```
p1.insert(3,5);
```

Which sets index 5 of your array to be 3 so now you have 1*x+3x^5 and last you call

```
p1.sub(5,8);
```

Which subtracts 5 from the value in the 8 index of your array so now you have 
1x^1 + 3x^5 + -5x^8